# Sorting a custom list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I would like to sort my custom implementation of a list, but it throws a compilation error I don't understand.

Code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class CustomList<E> extends ArrayList<E>
{
    public void sort()
    {
        Collections.sort(this);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
CustomList.java:8: error: no suitable method found for sort(CustomList<E>)
                Collections.sort(this);
                           ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: E
        lower bounds: Comparable<? super T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where E,T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    E extends Object declared in class CustomList
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
1 error
```

Comment: Please add minimum reproducible code.

Comment: @GauravJeswani This is reproducible, just use `javac CustomList.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
public class CustomList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends ArrayList<E>
{
    public void sort()
    {
        Collections.sort(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)

Sort expects the generic type E to be a subtype of Comparable<E>, if you don't want to constrain your generic type, you'll either need to supply a comparator capable of comparing two `E`s with each other or you'll have to come up with a method of sorting two objects you know nothing about... (i.e. why they need that constraint)

You could use object id, but that's not a very meaningful order

Comment: If I change `CustomList<E>` to `CustomList<String>` I still get the same error

Comment: Change where? In the definition? The definition doesn't care about the "name" written into the brackets. CustomList<String> is identical to CustomList<E> as far as the compiler is concerned, you need to add a type constraint. Like CustomList<E extends Comparable<? super E>>.

<? super E> means the comparator accepts the type E and any of its super type. For example <? super Integer> supertype Number and Object.